# Jekyll Blog Not Displaying Properly After Pointing to Custom Domain

Tags: css, layout, github, jekyll, blogs

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this issue but no sources address this directly. I have a Jekyll Blog setup through Github at: http://jwolfe890.github.io/johns_tech_blog/

I went through the process of setting up a CNAME, purchasing a domain and hosting and connecting this domain to GITHUB.

However, once the connection was made between my host (namecheap) and Github, the blog was published/redirected to my custom domain www.johnwolfe.tech however the css formatting and links no longer work. Although it does work if I run jekyll serve and access the link through that approach.

While some sources have discussed this issue when it occurs directly with github, I haven't found any sources that address when the wrong layout occurs because of adding a custom domain name, so I'm lost.

The github repository for the blog is:

https://github.com/jwolfe890/johns_tech_blog

The custom domain I added was:

johnwolfe.tech

And the original github link was:

jwolfe890.github.io/johns_tech_blog/

Thank you very much for your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `baseurl` in *_config.yml*.

```
baseurl: ""
```

And the way you call your css in *_includes/head.html* :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

Bonus : Allowed markdown files extensions are, by default, **markdown, mkdown, mkdn, mkd, md**. That's why your *_posts/2016-06-6-my-fascination-with-css.**mdown*** is bugging.

Comment: Even with the .markdown, the link to that post from the homepage still is not correctly attached to the .css style sheet. i've tried simply going into the blog post and putting the right path in to the /main.css sheet but it didn't make any difference unless i'm previewing it in the browser.

Comment: Edited my answer for css path.

Comment: `baseurl: ""` not `baseurl: "/"` as it actually is in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `baseurl: ""` in _config.yml to `baseurl: "/"`.

The code in your head.html include is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">`

Jekyll renders this code as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">`. That code tries to find main.css relative to the page.

Add the / and the code rendered will be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">`. This will try to find main.css relative to the site root.

More info on relative paths - http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php